# Are there multiple versions of how Ganesa got an elephant head?

Tags: ganesha, birth

In addition to the main version (Siva cutting off his head)

Bard AI says

> Another story says that Ganesha was born with an elephant head. This story is often told to explain why Ganesha is associated with wisdom and strength. The elephant is a symbol of wisdom in many cultures, and its strength is evident in its large size and powerful trunk.

.........................

> In another version, Ganesha's head was cut off by a demon named Jambavan. Jambavan was a powerful demon who was trying to steal Parvati's jewels. Ganesha stood in his way, and Jambavan cut off his head. When Parvati saw what had happened, she was furious. She cursed Jambavan, and he was turned into a monkey. Parvati then asked Vishnu to find the head of the first animal he saw. Vishnu found the head of a white elephant, and he brought it back to Parvati. Parvati placed the elephant head on Ganesha's body, and Ganesha was brought back to life.

Are these stories based on scripture?